# Using an ExpressJS router with subdomains

Tags: node.js, express

Due to my shared-hosting situation, I was forced to have all incoming requests redirected to a non-80 port on localhost, which I did through htaccess. This mutates the HTTP host header to always say localhost, no matter what subdomain I try to request. Simple enough, I found a workaround to use x-forwarded-host instead, but this means that I'm not able to rely on any of the Express subdomain middleware packages currently available on NPM, as they all rely on that host header (as far as I'm aware).

So I managed to send requests to the router. But for some reason, any request handling I try to do with the router for the specific subdomain that I have activated, won't get picked up by the router, and passes straight on through to the 404 handler.

`/index.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 30001;

const subdomainHosts = [];
fs.readdirSync('./routes/subdomain').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')).forEach(host => {
    subdomainHosts.push(host.split('.js')[0]);
});

const forwardSubdomain = require('./middlewares/forwardSubdomain');
app.use(forwardSubdomain(subdomainHosts));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/404.html'));
});
```

`/middlewares/forwardSubdomain.js`:

```js
module.exports = (subdomainHosts) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        let host = req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] ? req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] : '';
        host = host.split(':')[0].split('.example.com')[0];

        const isSubdomain = (host && subdomainHosts.includes(host));
        if (isSubdomain) {
            const subdomainRouter = require(`../routes/subdomain/${host}.js`);
            return subdomainRouter(req, res, next); 
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

`/routes/subdomain/test.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'test')));

module.exports = router;
```

`/test/` contains a simple hello world index.html. Yet, trying to access test.example.com gives me the 404.

I'm pretty certain that I'm missing something obvious, but I've been sitting on this for a bit too long, hence the cry for help.